# Javascript code not working? Tell me why

Tags: javascript, html

I was working on a simple javascript code and I don't know what it is not working.
Please tell me if you figure this out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayText(){
var xa = document.getElementById('abcd').innerHTML;
xa+= 'asdf';
}

displayText();  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="abcd"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`innerHTML` returns a String of the current contents of the element and not a pointer to it. So use this instead:

```
function displayText(){
  document.getElementById('abcd').innerHTML += 'asdf';
}
```

or

```
function displayText(){
  var el = document.getElementById('abcd'); 

  var xa = el.innerHTML;
  xa += 'asdf';

  el.innerHTML = xa;
}
```

Furthermore you can not call the function, before the element you are referring to is actually created. So move the call at the bottom of the body tag.

```
<!-- .... -->
<script>
  display();
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time the code runs the body (including your div) has not yet been parsed. `getElementById('abcd')` doesn't find anything at that time.

Either move your script element to the end of the body so that it runs *after* the body has been parsed, or call your `displayText()` function from an `onload` handler.

(And if you intend the new value in `xa` to be displayed in the same field you'll need to write it back to the element with `document.getElementById('abcd').innerHTML = xa`.)